# One method for several buttons?

Tags: android

Instead of have to call separate method for each button, would it be possible to just use one method and check which button it was that was clicked by it's id?

I'm using the simple way like `android:onClick="activateButtons"`

```
public void activateButtons(View v)
{
    if(?? == btn_1)
    {
    Code for button with ID = btn_1
    }
    if(?? == btn_1)
    {
    Code for button with ID = btn_2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you tag the buttons with an Id. Set the `android:id="@+id/yourbuttonid"` in the xml file. Then do `if(v.getId() == R.id.yourbuttonid)` in the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can assign specific ids(eg: button1) for buttons and then call v.getId() in activateButtons(onclick method) to check if it is equal to R.id.button1 and then do your operation there.

Cheers,

Richie

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClickKeyPad(View view)
{
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_password);

    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button_0:
        text.setText(text.getText() + "0");
    break;
    case R.id.button_1:
        text.setText(text.getText() + "1");
    break;

    case R.id.button_cancel:
        finish();
    break;

    default:
    break;
    }
}
```